# Mongodb filter by categories

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have Product collection. In this collection each document has same keys and different values.
Several documents are shown in the example below.

```
[
  {
    "productCategory": "Electronics",
    "price": "20",
    "priceCondition": "Fixed",
    "adCategory": "Sale",
    "productCondition": "New",
    "addDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adipisicing Elit Maxime Ab Nesciunt Dignissimos.",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "rating": {
      "oneStar": 1,
      "twoStar": 32,
      "threeStar": 13,
      "fourStar": 44,
      "fiveStar": 1
    },
    "click": 12,
    "views": 3
  },
  {
    "productCategory": "Automobiles",
    "price": "1500",
    "priceCondition": "Negotiable",
    "adCategory": "Rent",
    "productCondition": "New",
    "addDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adipisicing Elit 
  Maxime Ab Nesciunt Dignissimos.",
    "city": "California",
    "rating": {
      "oneStar": 2,
      "twoStar": 13,
      "threeStar": 10,
      "fourStar": 50,
      "fiveStar": 4
    },
    "click": 22,}
  },
  {
    "productCategory": "Hospitality",
    "price": "500",
    "priceCondition": "Yearly",
    "adCategory": "Booking",
    "productCondition": "New",
    "addDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adipisicing Elit Maxime Ab Nesciunt Dignissimos.",
    "city": "Houston",
    "rating": {
      "oneStar": 16,
      "twoStar": 19,
      "threeStar": 28,
      "fourStar": 16,
      "fiveStar": 17
    },
    "click": 102,
    "views": 47
  }
]
```

I would like to search each document with one or more matching search queries to match the document with my search.

In the example below, I will show url query:
`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/filter?productCondition=New&price=100&productCategory=Hospitality`

So far I have tried to solve the filtration using the $or and $and operators but here there is a problem because with the first operator $or when I do a query only the first condition is searched, the rest is omitted, with the second operator $and I have to add all the condition and the problem arises because I will not always have all querys.

I am using the find method to achieve my filtering methods.

```
db.collection(Index.Add)
  .find({
    $or: [
      { productCategory },
      { price },
      { adCategory },
      { priceCondition },
      { productCondition },
      { city },
    ],
  })
  .limit(pageSize)
  .skip(pageSize * parsePage)
  .toArray();

db.collection(Index.Add)
  .find({
    $and: [
      { productCategory },
      { price },
      { adCategory },
      { priceCondition },
      { productCondition },
      { city },
    ],
  })
  .limit(pageSize)
  .skip(pageSize * parsePage)
  .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to build filters for your products listing API. On any listing page, if one applies two or more simultaneous filters one expects an `and` of all those filters. So, a query like this `productCondition=New&price=100` should get all the products where `productCondition` is `New` and `price` is `100`.

Therefore, in order to filter we should go for an `$and` operator in `find` query. As you rightly said you might not have all the query params in your path always, so a condition like this:

```
$and: [
  { productCategory },
  { price },
  { adCategory },
  { priceCondition },
  { productCondition },
  { city },
]
```

would send `null` or `undefined` to the database values for the keys that don't exist in the query param and you might get unexpected results.

To handle this, you should build the `$and` query based upon what is there in your query params like this (assuming you're using express.js):

```
let conditions = [];
for(const param in req.query) {
  if(req.query[param]) {
    conditions.push({ param: req.query[param] });
  }
}
```

`conditions` will only contain the keys whose values are there in the query params. You can then pass the `conditions` variable to the query like this:

```
db.collection(Index.Add)
  .find({
    $and: conditions
  })
  .limit(pageSize)
  .skip(pageSize * parsePage)
  .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing me to a solution. My solution is a banned query that is undefined. And just apply the valid query to find method.
Example:

```
const {
  page,
  productCategory,
  price,
  priceCondition,
  adCategory,
  productCondition,
  city,
}: IAdds = req.query;

const check = (object: IAdds) => {
  for (let key in {
    productCategory,
    price,
    priceCondition,
    adCategory,
    productCondition,
    city,
  }) {
    if (object[key] !== undefined) return req.query;
  }
};
const resultFromCheckQuey = check(req.query);
const { page, ...res } = resultFromCheckQuey;
const filterResult = await db
    .collection(Index.Add)
    .find({
      $and: [res],
    })
    .limit(pageSize)
    .skip(pageSize * parsePage)
    .toArray();
```